Is every smooth function equal to its Laurent series?
It's known that there exists non-analytic smooth functions, take for example the function $f$ defined by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = \exp(-1/x^{2})$. $f$ has the zero polynomial as its Taylor series centred at $x = 0$, however, we can (somewhat) fix this by considering its Laurent series, that is,
$$f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{1!x^{2}} + \frac{1}{2!x^{4}} - \frac{1}{3!x^{6}} + \frac{1}{4!x^{8}} - \frac{1}{5!x^{10}} + ...$$
Although, this isn't really a fix I dont think since i'm not entirely sure if the series matches for $f(0) = 0$, but numerically, it seems to match in the region $(-\infty, -\varepsilon) \cup (\varepsilon,\infty)$, which is similar to an annulus. Is there a precise formulation of this phenomenon? Perhaps every smooth function is equal to its Laurent series in some annulus centred at the centre of which you take the Laurent series? Or every holomorphic function is equal to its Laurent series in some annulus?

Ah, a shame. Thank you @MartinR . Is it true, however, every complex holomorphic function is equal to its Laurent series in some annulus? Or is there examples similar to the function above for the real case?

Every holomorphic function in an annulus is representable as a Laurent series in that annulus.

Thank you very much.

Your example works because $f(x) = g(1/x)$ for $x \ne 0$ with the holomorphic function $g(z) = \exp(-z^2)$ satisfying $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x) = 0$.
But the function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $g(x) = \exp(-1/x^{2})$ for $x > 0$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ is also smooth (i.e. $g \in C^\infty(\Bbb R))$ but not representable as a Laurent series in any domain $0 < |x| < R$ (as can be concluded from the identity theorem for holomorphic functions).
